# how can i render jinja table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to render table in flask and jinja, I'm Beginner in programming.

```
@app.route('/')
def table():
    A = {'a1': {'B': 'b1', 'C': 'c1', 'D': {'d1': {'f1': 40.0, 'f2': 38.0},
                                            'd2': {'f1': 60.0, 'f2': 58.0}}},
         'a2': {'B': 'b1', 'C': 'c1', 'D': {'d1': {'f1': 30.0, 'f2': 28.0},
                                            'd2': {'f1': 70.0, 'f2': 66.0}}}
         }

    return render_template("templates/index.html", data=A)
```

Desired output look like:

[image]

jinja2 html:(skip thead i did it)

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">

    <thead>.....</thead>

    {% for key, value in data.items() %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ key }}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

How can i extract keys and values from A dict and looped in jinja. Appreciate any help to get me close to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `items()` a few times because you work with `dict` of `dicts` here is an example:

```
from jinja2 import Template


data = {
    'a1': {
        'B': 'b1',
        'C': 'c1',
        'D': {'d1': {'f1': 40.0, 'f2': 38.0}, 'd2': {'f1': 60.0, 'f2': 58.0}},
    },
    'a2': {
        'B': 'b1',
        'C': 'c1',
        'D': {'d1': {'f1': 30.0, 'f2': 28.0}, 'd2': {'f1': 70.0, 'f2': 66.0}},
    }
}

# your index.html template...
t = Template("""
    <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th rowspan="3">A</th>
              <th rowspan="3">B</th>
              <th rowspan="3">C</th>
              <th colspan="4">D</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th colspan="2">d1</th>
              <th colspan="2">d2</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>f1</th>
              <th>f2</th>
              <th>f3</th>
              <th>f4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for a_name, a_items in data.items() %}
                {% for d_key, d_items in a_items['D'].items() %}
                    {% for f_key, f_val in d_items.items() %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ a_name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ a_items['B'] }}</td>
                            <td>{{ a_items['C'] }}</td>
                            <td>{{ d_key }}</td>
                            <td>{{ f_key }}</td>
                            <td>{{ f_val }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
""")

print(t.render(data=data))
```

more convenient to work with a `list` of `dicts`:

```
data = [
    {'A': 'a1', 'B': 'b1', 'C': 'c1', 'D': 'd1', 'f1': 40, 'f2': 38},
    {'A': 'a1', 'B': 'b1', 'C': 'c1', 'D': 'd1', 'f1': 60, 'f2': 58},
    # ...
]

# template
{% for record in data %}
    <tr>
        <td> {{ record['A'] }} </td>
        <td> {{ record['B'] }} </td>
        <td> {{ record['C'] }} </td>
        <td> {{ record['D'] }} </td>
        <td> {{ record['f1'] }} </td>
        <td> {{ record['f2'] }} </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried your answer but it does not work, it duplicated rows in html table. please if you can modify your answer i will accepted

Comment: list of dicts approach is work with slightly modification, but how can i convert dict of dicts to look same as you illustrated above. As well, is this will affect the performance?@DanilaGanchar